# Repeated Unexpected Inconsistency errors...hard drive gone bad?

Tags: hard-drive, fsck

I have gotten a `Unexpected Inconsistency` error for the fourth time on my laptop in the last couple of weeks. The first three times was when I was running Ubuntu 16.04. `fsck` managed to fix the corrupt segments twice but on the third time it kept failing, and so I formatted the disk with Linux Mint 18.

It was working fine for the last week or so but gave me the same `Unexpected Inconsistency: Run fsck Manually` error again today.

Does this mean that there's something wrong with my hard drive?
How can I find out?

UPDATE: SMART Results
[image]

Comment: What other tools have you used to verify the health status of the disk?

Comment: None, read about SMART but wasn't sure what tool to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run the Disks utility (`gnome-disks`).
2. Select your hard drive.
3. Select the menu button in the top-right corner.
4. Click SMART Data & Self-Tests

For information on the attributes and which ones are critical, visit:
[S.M.A.R.T. - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes)

**EDIT:** Yes.  Your hard drive is failing.  If you want to recover any data, turn it off now, and research recovery options.

I recommend running the Linux utility `ddrescue`, but that is outside the scope of the question you asked.

Comment: I'm facing a host of problems just getting gnome-disks setup. I'll do that and update with the results. Thanks!

Comment: I have added a screenshot with the SMART test results. Not a good sign right?

Comment: Yes.  Your drive is failing.  Turn it off.  Research recovery options from another device.